# Warning: Each Child in an Array or Iterator Should Have a Unique “Key” Prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

When i map an array with Picker item i got the following warning:

> Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop.

Here is my code

```
var locationArray = [{"name":"canada","id":"2"},{"name":"sweden","id":"3"}];

var Locations = locationArray.map(function(result) {
return <Picker.Item label={result.name} value={result.id} /> ;
});

return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Picker selectedValue={this.state.location} onValueChange={(location) => this.setState({location:location})} style={[styles.picker, {color: '#2E3740'}]}>
                {Locations}
            </Picker>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
);
```

Comment: where? i mean where is the code?

Comment: Please attach code and also define what you are trying to achieve and where you got this exception.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this error message literally includes a link to a page describing how to fix it... That might just be the web-based version of React though. http://fb.me/react-warning-keys

Comment: Please (re)take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) If you continue posting [questions received poorly](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4124714/anwar-hussain?tab=questions), eventually you won't be able to post questions anymore.

Comment: I don't see your question.

Comment: What is not clear about the warning? It says that something is missing, so you should probably add what's missing.

Comment: what's wrong with that code? when i map that array i got this warning. I don't see anything missing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Better performance

This is a suggestions of reactjs to improve the rendering performance.
By [providing a unique key](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for each dynamically created element, it is possibile to minimize possible DOM changes.

### Update your code

Use the id of each element as a unique key. Alternatively would it be possible to use the index of each element.

```
var locationArray = [{"name":"canada","id":"2"},{"name":"sweden","id":"3"}];

var Locations = locationArray.map(function(result) {
return <Picker.Item key={result.id} label={result.name} value={result.id} /> ;
});

return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Picker selectedValue={this.state.location} onValueChange={(location) => this.setState({location:location})} style={[styles.picker, {color: '#2E3740'}]}>
                {Locations}
            </Picker>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same warning message and was able to overcome it by adding a unique key to the return object like in the below code.

Code with warning message

```
 getBatchList() {
    return this.state.availableBatch.map((data) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton value={data.label}>
                <Text style={styles.batchText}>{data.label}</Text>
            </RadioButton>   
        )
    })
 }
```

Code without warning message

```
 getBatchList() {
    //LIKE THIS
    var keyId=1;
    return this.state.availableBatch.map((data) => {
        return (
            <RadioButton value={data.label} key={keyId}>
                <Text style={styles.batchText}>{data.label}</Text>
            </RadioButton>   
        )
        keyId = keyId+1;
    })

}
```